# Raspbian SD Card Size

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, raspbian-jessie

I have a 16 GB SD card and I installed it on the Raspbian operating system. But when I type `df -h` on the terminal screen it shows 4.5 GB.

*Operating System : Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 Jessie*

```
$df -h

Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2       4.5G  4.1G  152M  97% /
udev                 435M     0  435M   0% /dev
tmpfs                 88M  8.6M   79M  10% /run
tmpfs                437M     0  437M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                437M     0  437M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1       256M  209M   47M  82% /boot
```

Comment: did you expand the filesystem? sudo raspi-config

Comment: How will I do ? What should I do after the "sudo raspi-config" phase?

Comment: the first option in raspi-config is expand root filesystem

Comment: Is there any reason you installed an obsolete OS? (I also wonder how)

Comment: @Milliways: How? [Here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_lite/images) are all the older images of rapbian lite

Comment: Clearly there is no specific reason. I thank you for everything my problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this is a fairly standard problem on older versions of Raspbian.

You need to tell the system to expand the root filesystem to use the available space on the SD card.  To do this, follow these instructions:

(Optional, but recommended: Go out and re-image with the latest version of the Raspbian OS.  As of this writing, that would be Stretch. Jessie is outdated at this time.  With Stretch you shouldn't see this problem as it will auto-expand for you.)

For older versions:

1. Boot into the Pi and login as the `pi` user (password=`raspberry`)
2. At the command prompt, type `sudo raspi-config`
3. Select the first option `Expand Filesystem`
4. The app will go out and apply the necessary changes, then reply with the message `Root partition has been resized. The filesystem will be enlarged upon the next reboot`
5. Select `OK`, then select `Finish`
6. When prompted to reboot, select `Yes`

Your Pi will reboot.  When you login next time, try the `df -h` command again.  The root filesystem should expand now to use up the rest of the SD card space.

Write back here to Let us know if this works for you (and if so, please mark this as the answer).

Good luck!

Comment: In fact it is an uncommon problem. All recent versions of Raspbian automatically resize the filesystem on initial boot.

Comment: @Milliways - You are correct.  I have amended my answer to clarify. Thanks!